# ruby on rails can i use something like Model.find(params[:id]).where()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, where-clause, rails-activerecord

Hi, I am still a student and I'm taking a software engineering course and we have this big project (web design) and we're using rails so my question is I have a table `Users` and a table `Groups` and another association table `GroupUsers` where it has two foreign keys `user_id` and `group_id`. Whenever a user creates or join an already created group his id and the group_id are added to `GroupUsers` table

```
module GroupUsersHelper
   def join
      @group_id = params[:id]
      @user_id = params[:user_id]
      @newuser= GroupUser.new(:group_id => @group_id, :user_id => @user_id)
      @newuser.save
      redirect_to(:controller => 'groups', :action => 'show', :id => @group_id)
   end
end
```

Now I have to create method leave group where I'll have to destroy the record from `GroupUsers`, so I wrote this code also in `GroupUsersHelper`

```
  def leave
      @group_id = params[:group_id]
      @user_id = params[:user_id]
      @group_user_id = params[:group_user_id]
      @newuser= GroupUser.find(@group_user_id).where(:group_id => @group_id, :user_id =>
      @user_id)
      @newuser.destroy
      redirect_to(:controller => 'groups', :action => 'show', :id => params[:id])
   end
```

but I get this error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in GroupsController#leave
```

Couldn't find `GroupUser` without an ID

If you need more info about the code please let me know.

Comment: add the view to see how your calling it

Answer (score 2):

The other answers addressed your code example, but not the question in the title. You cannot use `Model.find(params[:id]).where()` in ActiveRecord (Rails' default ORM). Model.find returns a single record (an instance of your Model class) but Model.where returns a Model::ActiveRecord_Relation object (an array-like object). The `.where` method is only available on your Model class directly (i.e. `Model.where`) or on an ActiveRecord_Relation. If you are chaining methods, you need to make sure each method returns an ActiveRecord_Relation. For example:

```
Model.where("name = ?", "max")
     .order(created_at: :desc)
     .reorder(created_at: :asc)
     .includes(:sent_comments)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Model.find(params[:id]) will generate such kind of query

 *Lets take an example : GroupUser.find(params[:id]) will generate sql equivalent*
 select * from group_users where id = params[:id]

If you want to add where condition do something like this
GroupUser.where("# id ={params[:id]} and someColumn = #{somevariable}")
```

Comment: my concern is that why you want to do this if find method automatically place where condition on id. and ids are by default primary keys in rails app.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the `groupuser_id` in the params hash. Instead of storing it in the `@group_id` and `@user_id`, just try this:

```
@newuser= GroupUser.find_by_group_id_and_user_id(params[:group_id],params[:user_id])
```

Can you additionally post your params dump so we can figure out how to make a good redirect since i hence that will be a problem also.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
user = User.find(params[:user_id])
group.users.delete(user)
group.save
```

This will remove the user from the users association, and will automatically destroy the GroupUser record when the group is saved. See the [collection.delete](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) method.

Answer (score 0):

@max pleaner is right, you should not use Model.find().where().

It is incorrect, and if you think about it, you will see that it is redundant. To find the association you wish to destroy, you either need params[:group_id] and params[:user_id], or just params[:group_user_id].

If you have passed the params[:group_user_id] to the leave method, you already have all the information needed to find the association:

```
def leave
  @newuser= GroupUser.find(params[:group_user_id])
  @newuser.destroy
  redirect_to(:controller => 'groups', :action => 'show', :id => params[:group_id])
end
```

Or alternatively, If you have passed the params[:group_id] and params[:user_id] to the leave method:

```
def leave
  @newuser= GroupUser.find_by_group_id_and_user_id(params[:group_id], params[:user_id])
  @newuser.destroy
  redirect_to(:controller => 'groups', :action => 'show', :id => params[:group_id])
end
```

Also, there are a few other redundancies in your code that you will notice I omitted above. There is no need to assign each parameter to an instance variable before passing the parameter to the find() method:

```
@model_id = params[:model_id]
@model= Model.find(@model_id)

#can be simplified to:

@model = Model.find(params[:model_id])
```

Generally, you only want to create instances variables for a record or collection of records you will need to access in a view (such as a Group in the context of your application).